# Wordpress trigger submisson form after video

Tags: wordpress, triggers, form-submit

I’m struggling to find a solution for this maybe you can help me out.
I’m working for first time in Wordpress. I’m using twenty twenty four theme. My code skills are close to nothing.
So… what I would like to do:

- Have a 30sec video with sound  as hero image.
- On top of that video a button to skip the video and go straight to the submission form
- if you don’t skip the video the form should appear once the video as finished

Could you help me with that? Is this something realistic?

Thank you in advance
Nadia

I've try to use cover block to have the skip video button, but once I do this this i have no sound on the video and the video is no longer responsive.
For the form I've try has pop up, but I couldn't manage the time delay and positioning on top of the video.